# keras.api._v1.keras.__internal__.legacy.layers' has no attribute 'embed_sequence

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am working on a chatbot based on a repo from here: https://github.com/Currie32/Chatbot-from-Movie-Dialogue/blob/master/Chatbot_Attention.py

I have changed the import tensorflow as tf to import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf.
I also have changed tf.contrib.xyz to tf.xyz (That is litteraly how I changed it, xyz is an example variable, not an actual tf function.) However, I get this error:

https://www.traff.co/en/services/text-host?id=6396 (Sorry, I could not put the error in here, otherwise flagged as "code".)

How do I fix this error? On Ubuntu 18.04, using python 3.10 & tensorflow-cpu.